# PostgreSQL(function) - Implementation of where clause to get rows by a value(concatenate) in the JSONB column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, where-clause

I am trying to get the rows from a table where I want the condition to check for a value from a jsonb column. The column stores the data as:

```json
[{"UserId": 420, "Permission": "Create"}, {"UserId": 369, "Permission": "View"}]
```

In the function, I check for the value using:

```sql
tab."Books" @> '[{"UserId":420}]'
```

but I want the 420 to be replaced with "ID" which I pass through the function. The only way I came across was concatenation(

```
tab."Books" @> '[{"UserId":'||ID||'}]'
```

which did not help.

Am I doing it wrong? Kindly suggest an alternative if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just `cast`:

```
tab."Books" @> ('[{"UserId":' || ID || '}]')::jsonb
```

Or you can use the json builder functions:

```
tab."Books" @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('UserId', ID))
```

Comment: Tried the first suggestion and it worked perfectly. Thank a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_build_object`, then convert that to a JSON array:

```
tab."Books" @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('UserId', id))
```